# How to make a fixed navbar while using flexbox?

Tags: css, menu, flexbox, position, navbar

I want to create a fixed navbar ,I know I surely need to use position:fixed;
But since I used display:flex before that,once I use position:fixed, the flex doesn't work.

Any friend a good solution?

```
<nav class="MyBlog-menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="">HOME</a></li>
        <li><a href="">CSS</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Python</a></li>
        <li><a href="">TECH</a></li>
        <li><a href="">OTHER</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
.MyBlog-menu{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    flex:1;
    justify-content: center;
    background-color: #98eebc;
    opacity:0.7;
    filter:alpha(opacity=70);
    border-radius: 4px;
    position: relative;
 height: 40px;
}
.MyBlog-menu ul{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    flex:0.33;
    list-style: none;
}
.MyBlog-menu ul li {
border-radius: 7px}

.MyBlog-menu ul li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #4c4c4c;
}
```

Comment: flex has nothing to do with the postionning of the container element ... simply use it correctly .. add position:fixed and width:100% and also top:0 left:0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `position: fixed` with `display: flex` is totally fine.

I suspect that when you added `position: fixed;` it caused the size of the `nav` to change. This is because when `position: fixed` is applied it takes the element out of the flow of the document. This means you'll need to explicitly define the size of the `nav` element.

```css
html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.MyBlog-menu {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex: 1;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: #98eebc;
  opacity: 0.7;
  filter: alpha(opacity=70);
  border-radius: 4px;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
}

.MyBlog-menu ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex: 0.33;
  list-style: none;
}

.MyBlog-menu ul li {
  border-radius: 7px
}

.MyBlog-menu ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #4c4c4c;
}
```

```html
<nav class="MyBlog-menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="">HOME</a></li>
    <li><a href="">CSS</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Python</a></li>
    <li><a href="">TECH</a></li>
    <li><a href="">OTHER</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<main>
 Content <br/>
 Content <br/>
 Content <br/>
 Content <br/>
 Content <br/>
 Content <br/>
 Content <br/>
 Content <br/>
 Content <br/>
 Content <br/>
 Content <br/>
 Content <br/>
 Content <br/>
 Content <br/>
 Content <br/>
 Content <br/>
 Content <br/>
 Content <br/>
 Content <br/>
 Content <br/>
 Content <br/>
 Content <br/>
 Content <br/>
 Content <br/>
 Content <br/>
 Content <br/>
 Content <br/>
 Content <br/>
 Content <br/>
 Content <br/>
 Content <br/>
 Content <br/>
 Content <br/>
 Content <br/>
 Content <br/>
 Content <br/>
 Content <br/>
 Content <br/>
 Content <br/>
 Content <br/>
 Content <br/>
 Content
</main>
```

Comment: oh all this br ending with slash :)

Answer (score 1):

When you add `position:fixed` to `.MyBlog-menu` the context of the element changes. It's now kind of floating above the other content, and loses it's "full page" width and position. You can resposition the menu using the attributes `top, bottom, left, right`.

For more information about the position attribute in CSS, check out following site: https://cssreference.io/property/position/

Resulting, if you want to keep the spacing as in your example, you can do following:

```
.MyBlog-menu{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    flex:1;
    justify-content: center;
    background-color: #98eebc;
    opacity:0.7;
    filter:alpha(opacity=70);
    border-radius: 4px;
    height: 40px;

    left:10px;
    right:10px;
    top:10px;
    position: fixed;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/0bv04rso/5/